# Micromax Unite 2 A106 updated to Lollipop version and no network or sim detected

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sim-card, mobile-network, micromax-unite

Using Micromax Unite 2 A106, updated to latest version of lollipop, after finalization and restarting my phone is not able to detect any SIM/network. Also no display of selection of Mobile network is displayed in the Settings.

If I try to dial any number the msg "Please close the airplane mode" is displayed. I tried reverting back to old version, removing the battery for 5-10 min, replaced another SIM network, but no change in the problem

Comment: Are you sure the Airplane mode is turned-off? And do you have any app that enables auto-airplane mode? If so please disable and check.

Comment: Lucky - i don't know but no network is shown on the taskbar ; + when i dial a no. a msg shown that turn off the airplane made

Comment: Please post some screenshots: 1) when you dial something and see the airplane mode message, 2) default home screen, and then of quick notification bar, 3) **Settings** and then **Settings -> More**, 4) type `*#*#4636#*#*` -> Phone Information -> and take screenshot, select preferred network mode and take screenshot. 5) Go to Settings -> About and take screenshot. Remember to post all these screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

me and my sis using this phone for almost 10 months...
First my sis upgraded her phone by downloading the official fota upgrade file from her phone and installed it. She also got same network issue.
Then I went to nearest service center and ask them about that issue and they had told me not to install by your own because it will delete the IMEI registration.
Then i had upgraded mine and my sister's phone to lollipop 5.0 in nearest service center.
Hope your problem will be resolved soon...

Comment: i understand and got same reply from company's service centre,

Answer (score 0):

If the Plane symbol(**✈**) is displayed in you notification you have your airplane mode turned on. This wont allow outgoing/incoming calls and displays a message to first turn off the airplane mode to make calls.

Goto `Settings -> More -> Airplane Mode -> Toggle off`.

Or Simply open your notification by swiping from the top of the phone screen and tap the Airplane mode and now you will be able to make calls.

[image: Screenshot_NotificationBar]

Also if you have any auto-airplane mode apps installed please disable it. If nothing works atlast you need to [flash stock ROM firmware your Micromax Unite A106](http://www.androidrootguide.com/2015/04/how-to-flash-stock-rom-firmware-on-micromax-unite-2-a106.html) or claim warranty and replace your device. [Related](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79807#c3)

Comment: i understand , but there is no plane symbol on the taskbar ,there is message to turn off the airplane mode when i try to make a call,also there is no detection of the sim cards/network by the phone ,even in the setting

Comment: the airpkane mode is completely stopped by me then also the msg when calling

Comment: @HimanshuShah Have you installed any tasker of auto-airplane mode apps in your phone?

Comment: Your answer unfortunately doesn't address: *Also no display of selection of Mobile network is displayed in the Settings.* Airplane mode doesn't hide Mobile Network settings.

Comment: @Firelord OP doesn't said the setting is hidden and what he meant to say is he wasn't able to make a selection of the mobile network(toggle of sim card enable/disable)..and only when the airplane mode is on I'm unable to enable the SIM network. It takes no action on selecting the toggle button and no message is displayed.

Comment: Up until Kitkat, ''Mobile Networks'' was under Settings -> More, and "Sim Management" (for dual SIM) was under **Settings** for Micromax devices. In my Lollipop (single SIM, other OEM), "Mobile Networks" is directly under Settings. That said, in Kitkat if Airplane Mode is enabled then you can always see the "SIM Management" but not toggle while "Mobile Networks" is always greyed out. Are you saying that all of this has changed in Lollipop? I guess OP could make this clear by posting the screenshots I asked.

Comment: @Firelord in my Lollipop dual sim now I have Settings -> Sim cards which shows two SIM cards names with a toggle to enable/disable. I can't enable(greyed out) both the SIM if I have Airplane mode turned on. And the Mobile Networks is under Settings-> More -> Mobile Networks. It is greyed out when the Airplane mode is enable or When I completely remove the sim card whether or not Airplane mode enable/disable.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your IMEI number got wiped. There are many tools online that can help you restore your original IMEI number.

As this phone has a Mediatek chipset, it shouldn't be hard to do that by your own.